# Priority Queue using heap, values with same key don't follow FIFO (first in first out)

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue, fifo

So I'm trying to create this priority queue to handle my "Order" objects, I'm running into a problem where an object containing the same key/priority will be placed at an early earlier position than others initialized first. I have provided the expected and received output alongside the 83 lines of code of how I constructed my heap with notes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Order {
    int value = -1;
    int priority = -1;
    bool operator <(Order const& RHS) { return priority < RHS.priority; } 
};

class heap {
private:
    std::vector<Order> orders{ Order{} };
    int size{}; //initalizes it at 0
    int p(int index) { return index >> 1; } 
    int l(int index) { return index << 1; } 
    int r(int index) { return (index << 1) + 1; } 
public:
    bool isEmpty() const { return size == 0; }
    void shiftUp(int position);
    void shiftDown(int position);
    void add(Order new_entry);
    Order removeTop();
    Order& getTop() { return orders[1]; }
}; 

template <typename T> 
void mySwap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    heap h;
    h.add(Order{1,3}); h.add(Order{2,2});
    h.add(Order{3,3}); h.add(Order{5,1});
    h.add(Order{6,2}); h.add(Order{7,2});
    h.add(Order{8,3}); h.add(Order{9,1});
    h.add(Order{23,3}); 
    std::cout << "value" << "     key(priority)" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Order temp = h.removeTop();
        std::cout << temp.value << "\t    " << temp.priority << "\n";
    }
}

void heap::shiftUp(int position) {
    if (position > size) return; 
    if (position == 1) return; 
    if (orders[p(position)] < orders[position]) { 
        mySwap(orders[position], orders[p(position)]);
        shiftUp(p(position));
    }
}

void heap::shiftDown(int position) {
    if (position > size) return; 
    int greaterPosition = position;
    if (l(position) <= size && orders[position] < orders[l(position)]) 
        greaterPosition = l(position);
    if (r(position) <= size && orders[greaterPosition] < orders[r(position)]) 
        greaterPosition = r(position);
    if (greaterPosition != position) { 
        mySwap(orders[position], orders[greaterPosition]);
        shiftDown(greaterPosition);
    }
}

void heap::add(Order new_entry) {
    if (size + 1 >= orders.size()) orders.push_back(Order{}); 

    orders[++size] = new_entry; 
    shiftUp(size); 
}

Order heap::removeTop() {
    Order temp = orders[1];
    mySwap(orders[1],orders[orders.size() - 1]); size--; 
    orders.pop_back(); 
    shiftDown(1); 
    return temp;
}
```

```
/*
        Expected Output

    Value           key(priority)
    1                   3
    3                   3
    8                   3
    23                  3
    2                   2
    6                   2
    7                   2
    5                   1
    9                   1


    Recieved/wrong Output

    value            key(priority)
    1                   3
    23                  3
    3                   3
    8                   3
    2                   2
    6                   2
    7                   2
    5                   1

*/
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use the debugger that is available for your compiler toolset.

Comment: Where would I locate this on VS?

Comment: There is a "Debug" option on the main menu.  Or just hit F10 and keep hitting F10./ F11  You will see the highlight move up (or down), executing a single line / function at a time.

Comment: Heaps, don't follow FIFO. I had to add a third element for a tire breaker and implement it into my operator overloading for < when keys/priorities were equal

Comment: is there a reason you don't use `std::priority_queue`, `std::push_heap` or `std::pop_heap`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54916335/56778

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57894388/56778

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code from answered information above

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Order {
    int value = -1;
    int priority = -1;
    int FIFO;
    bool operator <(Order const& RHS) {
        if (priority == RHS.priority)
            return FIFO > RHS.FIFO;
        else
            return priority < RHS.priority;
    } //compares keys for larger presidence 
};

class heap {
private:
    std::vector<Order> orders{ Order{} };
    int size{}; //initalizes it at 0
    int p(int index) { return index >> 1; } 
    int l(int index) { return index << 1; }  
    int r(int index) { return (index << 1) + 1; } 
public:
    bool isEmpty() const { return size == 0; }
    void shiftUp(int position);
    void shiftDown(int position);
    void add(Order new_entry);
    Order removeTop();
    Order& getTop() { return orders[1]; }
}; 

template <typename T> 
void mySwap(T& a, T& b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    heap h;
    h.add(Order{1,3}); h.add(Order{2,2});
    h.add(Order{3,3}); h.add(Order{5,1});
    h.add(Order{6,2}); h.add(Order{7,2});
    h.add(Order{8,3}); h.add(Order{9,1});
    h.add(Order{23,3}); 
    std::cout << "value" << "     key(priority)" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Order temp = h.removeTop();
        std::cout << temp.value << "\t    " << temp.priority << "\n";
    }
}

void heap::shiftUp(int position) {
    if (position > size) return; 
    if (position == 1) return; 
    if (orders[p(position)] < orders[position]) { 
        mySwap(orders[position], orders[p(position)]);
        shiftUp(p(position));
    }
}

void heap::shiftDown(int position) {
    if (position > size) return; 
    int greaterPosition = position;
    if (l(position) <= size && orders[position] < orders[l(position)]) 
        greaterPosition = l(position);
    if (r(position) <= size && orders[greaterPosition] < orders[r(position)]) 
        greaterPosition = r(position);
    if (greaterPosition != position) { 
        mySwap(orders[position], orders[greaterPosition]);
        shiftDown(greaterPosition);
    }
}

void heap::add(Order new_entry) {
    if (size + 1 >= orders.size()) orders.push_back(Order{});
    new_entry.FIFO = size + 1;
    orders[++size] = new_entry; 
    shiftUp(size); 
}

Order heap::removeTop() {
    Order temp = orders[1];
    mySwap(orders[1],orders[orders.size() - 1]); size--; 
    orders.pop_back(); 
    shiftDown(1); 
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, heap does not have FIFO property until you implement something that helps doing so. In your order class, you are only comparing using the priority value. In your `Order` class, you are comparing two `Orders` by only their priority value. You need a additional variable that serves as the purpose for recording the timing when that value was inserted, and compare according to that.

If you are using the variable `value` for that purpose, you need to specify in your overloaded `<` method, what do you want to do when two `Order's` `priority` values are equal. Currently, you are only using the `priority` variable to compare. You are not specifying what do you want to do when the `priority` of two `Orders` are equal. You have to specify what do you want to do when the `priority` value of two variables are equal. Maybe compare a timing variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I was struggling on that for the longest time! I posted the changes to my code below