# Is there a "Lifo" type priority queue in python in case of multiple elements with the same priority?

Tags: python, data-structures, priority-queue

I have two tuples with the same rank in a priority queue in python.
The get method will take the first element inserted.
If two elements have the same priority in the queue, I would like to get the last element inserted returned first :

```
#python 3.7
import queue
q= queue.PriorityQueue()
q.put((1, 'first_in'))
q.put((1, 'last_in'))
q.put((2, 'not_to_be_returned'))

for i in range(q.qsize()):
    print(q.get(i))

#Returns
(1, 'first_in')
(1, 'last_in')
(2, 'not_to_be_returned')

#looking for : 
(1, 'last_in') # in case of same rank return the last inserted
(1, 'first_in') 
(2, 'not_to_be_returned')

#Merci
```

Comment: I just noticed that 'first_in` was grabbed first because  first_in comes first alphabetically.  
     q= queue.PriorityQueue()  q.put((1, 'first_in'))    q.put((1, 'last_in')  q.put((1, 'abcdf')  returns  (1, 'abcdf'), (1, 'first_in'),  (1, 'last_in').    .can we add a second entry

Comment: @tessie, thank your for your insightful notice. Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need this ordering, the simplest way to solve it is to add a new 2nd element to your tuples that will be used to break ties when the 1st elements in two tuples are the same.

For LIFO ordering you use a counter that you decrement every time you insert.  Your elements then become:

```
q.put((1, 0, 'first_in'))
q.put((1, -1, 'last_in'))
q.put((2, -2, 'not_to_be_returned'))
```

Comment: Exactly right. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893840/priority-queue-remove-items-with-same-priority-first-one-entered/54916335#54916335) explains why you can't maintain insertion order in a heap-based priority queue, unless you maintain some kind of information about arrival time.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that would be `queue.LifoQueue`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.LifoQueue).

Comment: Thanks but lifo queue is no priority queue. l want to return the items with highest priority first , then perform a lifo selection if two items have same priority.

Comment: @greg well, this is not what you've asked in your question.

Comment: @go2nirvana The title of the question is: "Is there a “Lifo” type priority queue in python?".

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie, I just changed the code to be more explicit by adding another example.